# Enterprise library with linq-to-sql?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, enterprise-library, validation-application-bl

I wanted to get any feedback (put out a feeler) for how the enterprise library plays with linq-to-sql generated classes. I was considering using the validation handler to provide validation logic/display to the UI level. I am considering the caching handler, validation, and authorization handlers primarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at my articles about integrating Enterprise Library Validation Application Block with LINQ to SQL. In this series I explain how to effectively use the VAB with LINQ to SQL:

1. [Part 1: Basic Integration](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=46)
2. [Part 2: Using context within custom validators](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=47)
3. [Part 3: The complexity of custom validators](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=49)
4. [Part 4: Using Metadata to Automate Validations](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=64)